# Cron task not working on magento 1.9.2

Tags: php, magento, cron

I have been trying running a cron task on magento site ( on a sub-domain )

```
Magento version : 1.9.2.4 
PHP  :  5.6
```

I have tried the following option from my c-panel cron tab

Set  777 permssions for cron.php file

**Option 1 :**

*/15    *   *   *   *   php -q /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/cron.php

**Option 2 :**

0,30    *   *   *   *   /bin/sh /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/cron.sh

**Option 3:**

0   *   *   *   *   php /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/cron.php

---

But i couldn't get it working  with any of the option

** Response for the crons received in email :**

**Option 1  :**

Access denied.

**Option 3 :**

X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.14

Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Access denied.

**There is no email response for option 2**

---

**After reading the comments installed 'aoe scheduler'**

No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly. (See Instructions)

I modified cron ( from c-panel) as insrtructed by AOE scheduler as :

- - - - - ! test -e /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always --includeGroups my_queue_jobs
- - - - - ! test -e /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always --excludeGroups my_queue_jobs
- - - - - ! test -e /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default --includeGroups groupA,groupB
- - - - - ! test -e /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default --includeGroups groupC
- - - - - ! test -e /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default --excludeGroups groupA,groupB,groupC
          */10 * * * * ! test -e /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/maintenance.flag && cd /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/shell && /usr/bin/php scheduler.php --action watchdog

After doing all that i got the following results in email

**! test -e /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always --includeGroups my_queue_jobs**

```
/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable

/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable

/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource 
temporarily unavailable

/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable

/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable

Could not find a binary for php
```

**! test -e /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh --mode always --excludeGroups my_queue_jobs**

```
    /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
    /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
    /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
    /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
    /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

**! test -e /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default --includeGroups groupC**

```
/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

**! test -e /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default --includeGroups groupA,groupB**

```
/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

**! test -e /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/maintenance.flag && /bin/bash /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh --mode default --excludeGroups groupA,groupB,groupC**

```
/bin/bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/bin/bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/bin/bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/bin/bash: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
/home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/scheduler_cron.sh: fork: retry: Resource temporarily unavailable
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.14
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

**! test -e /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/maintenance.flag && cd /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/shell && /usr/bin/php scheduler.php --action watchdog**

```
Status: 500 Internal Server Error
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.6.14
Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Comment: did you checked by installing `aoe scheduler extension ?

Comment: add this 'aoe scheduler extension' https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html

Comment: nsdlfefinedieicbe i have tested it with aoe scheduler extension and  and  updated the result i got

Answer (score 0):

Try outputting to log file to trap error like

> 0,30 * * * * /bin/sh /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/cron.sh >>
>   path_to/magneto/var/filename.log

It will be ideal to use the a log file in magento var log folder.

When you choose to run the cron.php file do make sure of the php binary and use it with the path. To find the path use the following command

```
>which php
```

Comment: i will try this as well .

Comment: php path on server is  /usr/local/bin/php , where do i suppose put it in command you suggested

Comment: Try this */15 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/cron.php

Comment: Also you can try calling the cron file manually from the prompt like 
>/usr/local/bin/php -f /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/cron.php
or
>sh /home/XXXX/public_html/newmagento/cron.sh

Comment: i tried running it from command prompt : sh  /home/xxx/public_html/newmagento/cron.sh and /usr/local/bin/php -f /home/xxxx/public_html/newmagento/cron.php,  But didn't get any message in terminal, email , nor did the cron work

Comment: Do check your cron_schedule table in magento. All the scheduled and run cron details are logged there. If there were any error then that is also updated in the table. Just verify if your crons are ever being scheduled.